How to upload more than 100 files at once in github because it does not work for me?
How to upload more than 100 files at once in github?
I need assistance. I have 3 react projects i would love to upload on github
It keeps showing me Youza can’t upload 100 files at a time.
Should i send them to github through zipfiles. I’m new to react please I need help

You should use Git commands instead of the GitHub web interface, which has a limit on the number of files you can upload at once. You can follow this article steps, If you don't know how to use commands. Let us know if you found any issue while running these commands, Thanks.
